# ggplot2 - Insert title using file names

Tags: r

I need to plot several tables, in order to automatize the process, I would like to  use the files names and insert it as the title for each plots.

For example, the file names has the following naming scheme:

```
almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref.csv
```

My desired output, should looks like that:

```
Almourol daily discharge ref. period
```

For the moment I am using the following code:

```
almourol_ref <- read.table("almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", fill = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(tools)
title = file_path_sans_ext("almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref.csv")
title = strsplit(title, "_")
title = noquote(title)
title = paste(title[1],title[4], "discharge",title[5], period)
almourol_ref <- melt(almourol_ref, id.vars="DAYS")
png("almourol_ref.png", width = 600, height = 400)
p <- ggplot(almourol_ref, aes(DAYS,value, col=variable))
p + geom_line(size = 0.1) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), linetype="dotted") +
  ylab("Runoff [m3/s]") +
  xlab("Day") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank())+
  scale_color_discrete(name='Models GCM_HM') +
  ggtitle(title)
```

Unfortunately it does not work and any title is added to the graphs. Any ideas or hints are more than welcome.

Please find a minimal example of the data:

```
DAYS;GWFDisi;GSWIM;GGAP3;GHYPE;GVIC;HWFDisi;HSWIM;HGAP3;HHYPE;HVIC;IWFDisi
1;-308.78;-183.19;-232.48;-233.22;-150.38;-596.49;-311.58;-571.41;-387.63;-315.43;-451.26
2;-348.52;-192.39;-314.68;-231.67;-147.88;-563.14;-335.39;-558.46;-423.13;-355.14;-501.58
3;-416.24;-211.68;-436.83;-232.73;-164.87;-537.54;-327.19;-465.70;-455.62;-403.40;-458.43
4;-459.95;-217.75;-486.37;-228.07;-202.23;-560.68;-359.07;-497.20;-481.41;-430.87;-475.76
5;-437.58;-219.63;-494.34;-223.27;-249.18;-613.41;-371.47;-457.38;-499.42;-433.01;-446.02
6;-470.20;-228.91;-503.95;-217.41;-292.13;-618.50;-381.87;-505.86;-505.63;-430.23;-440.30
7;-500.54;-245.91;-527.91;-226.86;-319.97;-599.95;-381.06;-416.05;-474.56;-431.76;-526.32
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "any title" means in your case?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik- In my case "any title" means that nothing is added to the plot, it does not work.

Comment: This appears to work: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("New plot title")`. Can you provide an easy-to-paste example of your data?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - ggtitle("new plot title") also works for me. But here I would like to use the file names as a title, because I have to do more than 1000 different plots. What do you mean by easy to paste example of the data ? (there is already a minimal example of the data provided in the question)

Comment: If that's the case, this is not a ggplot2 issue at all. Then please spell out the general algorithm which converts `almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref.csv` to `Almourol daily discharge ref. period`. Easy to paste means I copy and paste it to my R session and I start coding. If I have to see which variable I need to use to make it work with your example and then think about how to import that chunk... some people may not bother.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to replicate the same plot using input data from a series of similarly-structured CSV files, and that you want the title if each plot to reflect the CSV file that its data came from?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - SO my file name is 'almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref.csv' in order to get rid of the csv extension I use 'title = file_path_sans_ext("almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref.csv")' then in order to get rid of the underscore I used 'title = strsplit(title, "_")'  then in order to get rid of the double quote I used 'title = noquote(title)'. Then I am encountering problem to add fix term to the different component of the title, because this line is not working 'title = paste(title[1],title[4], "discharge",title[5], "period")'; and the last line also is not working 'ggtitle(title)

Comment: @rensa - I do have several csv files that have the same structure as the provided one. I would like to use the file name of each csv files in order to insert a title to each plots.

Comment: Okay. Can you insert `print(title)` statements between your other statements? It looks like something's going wrong with the code that breaksbthe filename segments up and  proceses them into a title. I'd wager `title` is ending up as `character(0)` at some point.

Comment: @rensa my bet would be that `strsplit` returns a list and single `[` doesn't subset it correctly. :)

Comment: @Roman Yeah, that sounds about right :P

Comment: @rensa - so after 'title = file_path_sans_ext("almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref.csv‌​")' print return [1] "almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref"; after 'title = strsplit(title, "_")' print return [[1]]
[1] "almourol"   "gfdl-esm2m" "rcp8p5"     "daily"      "ref"  ; after  'title = noquote(title)' print return [[1]] [1] almourol   gfdl-esm2m rcp8p5     daily      ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you step through the code, line by line, it will be clear that something isn't working. In your case, the result of `strsplit` is a list of length 1, which holds the sliced vector. You can resolve this in a number of ways, one is to subset only the first element, or perhaps use `unlist(title)`.

```
title <- "almourol_gfdl-esm2m_rcp8p5_daily_ref.csv"
title <- strsplit(title, "_")[[1]]
title <- noquote(title)
title <- paste(title[1],title[4], "discharge",title[5], "period")
title

[1] "almourol daily discharge ref.csv period"
```